# How to select a specific href's(in arraytlist) and click them to test using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am facing some problem in a scenario where i want to test the navigation of a particular link in a webpage, but there are many links with same link text. I tried the below code

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println ("No of links in page = "+linkElements.size());

ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (WebElement a : linkElements) {
    System.out.println(a.getText()); 
    System.out.println(a.getAttribute("href"));
    hrefs.add(a.getAttribute("href")); 
}

int i=0;
for (String href : hrefs) {
    driver.navigate().to(href);
    String title = "404 Not Found";
    if (driver.getTitle().equals(title)) {
        System.out.println("\"" + href + "\" is navigating to error page");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\"" + href + "\" is working.");
    }
}
```

it takes all the links and navigate. but i want to navigate to only some links in the page.  Please help:)

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to the question, properly formatted.

Comment: what is the condition? I think an if statement in your for loop should do the trick.